# Draw a segmented circle in Android: OpenGL vs Cavans?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I need to draw something like this:

[image: Segmented circle with content on each segment]

I was hoping that [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874424/android-looking-for-a-drawarc-method-with-inner-outer-radius) posted some code of how he drew his segmented circle to begin with, but alas he didn't.

I also need to know which segment is where after interaction with the wheel - for instance if the wheel is rotated, I need to know where the original segments are after the rotation action.

**Two questions:**

1. Do I draw this segmented circle (with varying colours and content placed on the segment) with **OpenGL** or using Android **Canvas**?
2. Using either of the options, how do I **register which segment is where**?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I've figured out how to **[draw the segmented circle](http://android.okhelp.cz/draw-arc-android-basic-example/)** using `Canvas` (I'll post the code as an answer). And I'm sure I'll figure out how to rotate the circle soon. But I'm still unsure how I'll **recognize a separate segment of the drawn wheel** after the rotation action.

Because, what I'm thinking of doing is drawing the segmented circle with these wedges, and the sort of handling the entire `Canvas` as an `ImageView` when I want to rotate it as if it's spinning. But when the spinning stops, how do I differentiate between the original segments drawn on the `Canvas`?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've read about how to draw a [segment on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888564/956975) ([here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246898/956975)), [OpenGL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-in-android-using-opengl), [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and even [drawing shapes and layering them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384895/956975), but I've yet to see someone explaining **how to recognize the separate segments**.

Can [`drawBitmap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109514/956975) or [`createBitmap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25339220/956975) perhaps be used?

If I go with OpenGL, I'll probably be able to **rotate** the segmented wheel using [OpenGL's rotation](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion.html), right?

I've also read that OpenGL might be too powerful for what I'd like to do, so should I rather consider "[the graphic components of a game library built on top of OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309726/956975)"?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of answers my first question above - how to draw the segmented circle using Android `Canvas`:

Using the [code found here](http://android.okhelp.cz/draw-arc-android-basic-example/), I do this in the `onDraw` function:

```
    // Starting values
    private int startAngle = 0;
    private int numberOfSegments = 11;
    private int sweepAngle = 360 / numberOfSegments;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        setUpPaint();

        setUpDrawingArea();

        colours = getColours();

        Log.d(TAG, "Draw the segmented circle");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++) {

            // pick a colour that is not the previous colour
            paint.setColor(colours.get(pickRandomColour()));

            // Draw arc
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint);

            // Set variable values
            startAngle -= sweepAngle;
        }
    }
```

This is how I set up the drawing area based on the device's screen size:

```
private void setUpDrawingArea() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Set up drawing area.");

        // First get the screen dimensions
        Point size = new Point();

        Display display = DrawArcActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        Log.d(TAG, "Screen size = "+width+" x "+height);

        // Set up the padding
        int paddingLeft = (int) DrawArcActivity.this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_large);
        int paddingTop = (int) DrawArcActivity.this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_large);
        int paddingRight = (int) DrawArcActivity.this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_large);
        int paddingBottom = (int) DrawArcActivity.this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_large);

        // Then get the left, top, right and bottom Xs and Ys for the rectangle we're going to draw in
        int left = 0 + paddingLeft;
        int top = 0 + paddingTop;
        int right = width - paddingRight;
        int bottom = width - paddingBottom;

        Log.d(TAG, "Rectangle placement -> left = "+left+", top = "+top+", right = "+right+", bottom = "+bottom);

        rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
```

That (and the other functions which are pretty straight forward, so I'm not going to paste the code here) draws this: 
The segments are different colours with every run.

[image: Segmented circle]

Comment: where is setUpPaint() method?